# is this possible to pass npm module as props to reduce client side bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Is this possible to pass `npm module` as props in `NEXTjs` to reduce the bundle size of `client`.
I want checking this url
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-next-js-handbook/#analyzing-the-app-bundles
In this example developer pass `date`.

```
const moment = (await import('moment')).default()
  return {
    date: moment.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY'),
    post: posts[query.id]
  }
```

is there any way to pass `moment` object ?
I tried like this

```
 const moment = (await import("moment")).default();
  console.log("+++");
  console.log(moment);
  return {
    // revalidate: 200,
    props: {
      moment: JSON.stringify(moment),
      name: "jjjj"
    }
  };
```

But it is not working .I am getting error on client side

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wood-p6e3w?file=/pages/index.js:461-673

error

```
xx is not a function
    at IndexPage (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js:19:15)
    at processChild (/sandbox/node_modules/react-dom/cjs
```

**client side code**

```
export default function IndexPage({ moment, name }) {
  console.log(name, "client");
  var xx = JSON.parse(moment);
  console.log(xx().format("DD-MMM-YYYY"), "client");
```

Comment: Next props are only pojo and does not pass the functions afaik, besides its next and will bundle the page only. I would suggest to move to dayjs if you can

Comment: any way to reduce client side bundle size ..Actually I am using a `npm package` which increase my bundle size to 300kb

Comment: `npm package` contains logger function and some utitlity fuctions

Comment: @user944513 "_any way to reduce client side bundle size_": have you given this a look? https://thekevinwang.com/2021/03/15/reduce-first-load-js/ ;; what you are doing will not work as you are trying to convert a library (technically an object having functions) to string (and vice-versa), you should have instead just passed the moment object itself like `props: { moment, name: 'john doe'}`. But it is recommended to use [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) instead of implementing similar functionality yourself.

Comment: i tried dyamic import still not working.https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wood-p6e3w?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: @user944513 I have shared a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-currying-zlewp) on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68143512/11613622).