# TypeError: moment is not a function in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to import npm module dynamically .but getting this error
**TypeError: moment is not a function**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wood-p6e3w?file=/pages/index.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const moment = dynamic(() => import("moment"));
export default function IndexPage({ moment, name }) {
  console.log(moment());
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>Abouthhhh</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({
  preview = false,
  previewData = {},
  defaultLocale,
  locale,
  req,
  res
}) => {
  return {
    // revalidate: 200,
    props: {
      name: "jjjj"
    }
  };
};
```

I am taking reference from here
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: `moment` would probably be a "dynamic" component according to those docs?

Comment: `next/dynamic` is used to wrap a whole component not just a library import.

Comment: and your `moment()` call is not file level `moment`. it's getting `moment` variable from `IndexPage` props which is undefined. remove `moment` from `IndexPage` props.

Comment: @user944513 Have a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-currying-zlewp